# Libgdx incredibly high RAM usage!

Tags: libgdx, memory-efficiency, memory

Alright so I'm new to Libgdx and Game programming in general, and I've got a huge problem.

If I leave my game on, it will start to eat memory, pretty fast at that, until it reaches a point my PC hasn't enough so it forcefully shuts it down (I have 24GB of RAM!!!)

What could be the reason for this, I don't have FPS lag or anything.

Comment: Can you maybe show us some code? (Initializations, asset loading, game loop, etc.)

Comment: http://pastebin.com/LTWLp2wJ this is my main screen, do you see anything here?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like making a new SpriteBatch ever update wasn't such a smart idea of me!

Lesson learned!

Comment: You're also creating a new Texture every update, line 281. :)

Comment: Yeah I moved those to show and now it only uses 78mb of RAM!